# Putting domain name for wordpress instead of Public domain given by in aws-ec2

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, domain-name

I signed-up in AWS(Amazon Web server) for my Wordpress site. I also installed wordpress through AWS-ec2. I followed the steps inside AWs-ec2 documentation like LAMP and others needed.As I go through inside AWS-EC2 environment, I launched an instance where i can work for my Wordpress. Having an instance creates a default public domain name for my wordpress (http://ec2-xxx-xx-xxx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/).

Now, my problem is I want to make our own domain name like example.com as our wordpress site instead of default domain name given by AWS-ec2. and, what are other requirements or tools needed to deploy it? We bought our domain name in GoDaddy.

Your answers will be highly appreciated.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**DNS**

You need to start with setting up DNS. To do this you can use the service provided by Godaddy or use Route53 in amazon. You will set up records to point to your instance.

**Apache**

If you are using Virtualhosts, you will need to set up your Virtualhost to respond to the new domain name. If you are not using virtual hosting, it will return the same site regardless of which domain you used.

**Wordpress**

Wordpress does save the domain you installed it with in the settings. If you change the domain these settings may cause some issues. If you can't get into the Admin UI to fix this, update wp_options table in mysql.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It helps a lot.

But it seems i got a new problem again.When i tried to install theme for wordpress in aws-ec2, i got an error says "Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2014/10. Is its parent directory writable by the server?".